# java: represent Date with optional month and day

Tags: java, class, date, jodatime

I would like to store Date with optional month and day in java.
I know of the [`java.time.LocalYear`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html) class to store just the year.
Shall I create my own custom class to hold dates with optional month and day or are there any custom library to solve the problem.

```
public class Date {

  private LocalYear year;
  private int month;
  private int day;

  public Date(LocalYear year) {
   this.year = year;
  } 
  
  public Date(LocalYear year, int month) {
   this.year = year;
   this.month = month;
  }

  public Date(LocalYear year, int month, iny day) {
   this.year = year;
   this.month = month;
   this.day = day;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do any of [`java.time.Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html), [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html), or [`java.time.MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/MonthDay.html) meet your requirements?

Comment: What is your use case for this? In general, I would not recommend using a single class to represent multiple concepts of time. There is a reason `java.time` had to split it all up.

Comment: @Slaw you suggestion sounds good, I can wrap all: java.time.Year, java.time.YearMonth, or java.time.MonthDay  in a class and that would solve the problem.

Comment: Note there's already a class that encapsulates all those values (year, month, and day): [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Comment: Yes, But I can't make month day optional in that, with custom class wrapped around those 3 I can make the month day optional

Comment: No such class as `java.time.LocalYear`. There is [`Year`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Year.html).

Comment: Why the tag for *Joda-Time*? The creator of that library, Stephen Colebourne, went on to create its successor, the *java-time* classes built into Java 8 and later. You seem to be referring to *java.time*, so either explain or delete the `jodatime` tag.

Comment: Explain your business problem, as there likely is a better solution than devising a partial date class.

Comment: Avoid using `Date` as a class name. Java already includes two classes with that name.

Comment: What does it *mean* for them to be optional?

Comment: @Raedwald By optional I mean it can be empty, and use will not always provide the month and day information and could only provide year.

Answer (score 3):

It’s hard to guide you without knowing your use case. One option is using the `TemporalAccessor` interface as a common type for dates with and without month and/or day of month and then put either a `LocalDate`, a `YearMonth` or a `Year` into your variable (the last class is just called `Year` (not `LocalYear`, though it would have been in line with the naming scheme)). For example:

```
    List<TemporalAccessor> dates = List.of(
            LocalDate.of(2019, Month.OCTOBER, 3), // full date
            YearMonth.of(2019, Month.NOVEMBER), // no day of month
            Year.of(2020)); // no month or day of month
```

What can we use this for? One example:

```
    for (TemporalAccessor ta : dates) {
        System.out.println(ta);
        System.out.println("Year: " + ta.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
        if (ta.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
            System.out.println("Month: " + ta.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Month: undefined");
        }
        if (ta.isSupported(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            System.out.println("Day: " + ta.get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Day: undefined");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This outputs:

> ```
> 2019-10-03
> Year: 2019
> Month: 10
> Day: 3
>
> 2019-11
> Year: 2019
> Month: 11
> Day: undefined
>
> 2020
> Year: 2020
> Month: undefined
> Day: undefined
> ```

Whether or how well it fulfils your requirements I cannot tell.

Using `ChronoField` constants for access is low-level, so you may want to wrap the `TemporalAccessor` in a nice class with nice getters. For example:

```
public class PartialDate {

    private TemporalAccessor date;

    public PartialDate(Year year) {
        date = year;
    }

    public PartialDate(Year year, int month) {
        date = year.atMonth(month);
    }

    public PartialDate(Year year, int month, int day) {
        date = year.atMonth(month).atDay(day);
    }

    public Year getYear() {
        return Year.from(date);
    }

    public OptionalInt getMonthValue() {
        if (date.isSupported(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR)) {
            return OptionalInt.of(date.get(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR));
        } else {
            return OptionalInt.empty();
        }
    }

    // A similar getDay method

}
```

You may extend the class to your needs. Maybe you want constructors that accept a `Month` enum constant and/or a `YearMonth` object directly and/or getters that return those types wrapped in `Optional`s.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.